# How to delete a specific sub-folder in a parent folder using a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like to create a batch file deleting or removing the folder `C:\temp\root\students\type1`, its subfolder and all the files.

The folders and files I do have are as follows:

```
C:\temp
C:\temp\root
C:\temp\root\students
C:\temp\root\tutors
C:\temp\root\students\type1
C:\temp\root\students\type2
C:\temp\root\tutors\type1
C:\temp\root\tutors\type2
C:\temp\root\students\type1\details.txt
C:\temp\root\students\type1\assignment1
C:\temp\root\students\type1\assignment1\results.txt
```

The folder `C:\temp\root\students\type1\assignment1` is specified in the batch file.

I would like to go one folder/directory up and delete or remove `C:\temp\root\students\type1` in my batch file (test.bat).

Please help me with this.

Comment: C is a programming language, not whatever hard drive your stuff is on. This shouldn't be tagged C.

Comment: Where is your existing batch file command? Just change the folder to match your need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
rd /s /q C:\temp\root\students\type1
```

It will remove files and folders recursively, caution, without prompt. It's kind of a substitute for the good old deltree. Best.

EDIT: within your notepad, create your **mygoodbatch.bat** with this content:

```
md C:\temp
md C:\temp\root
md C:\temp\root\students
md C:\temp\root\tutors
md C:\temp\root\students\type1
md C:\temp\root\students\type2
md C:\temp\root\tutors\type1
md C:\temp\root\tutors\type2
md C:\temp\root\students\type1\details.txt
md C:\temp\root\students\type1\assignment1
md C:\temp\root\students\type1\assignment1\results.txt
rd /s /q C:\temp\root\students\type1
```

(**md** is the **make dir** dos command, so all the lines beginning with it are creating the folders - the last line is the one to del your level 4AA)

Save this batch on the root of your disk and then run it. I really wish this is what you want. What I yet didn't understand is: you are creating a directory structure and, at the same time, excluding level 4AA... is that it?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.

These are physical folders/directories.

Is there any way to retrieve this folder structure from the batch file and remove this particular folder?

What I meant by the folder structure is:

**C:\temp** is Level 1
**C:\temp\root** is Level 2
**C:\temp\root\students** is Level 3A
**C:\temp\root\tutors** is Level 3B
**C:\temp\root\students\type1** is Level 4AA
**C:\temp\root\students\type2** is Level 4AB
**C:\temp\root\tutors\type1** is 4BA
**C:\temp\root\tutors\type2** is 4BB

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I understood you correctly. The main principle is: anything you put in place of **C:\temp\root\students\type1**, from my answer above, anything inside this folder will be deleted.

Comment: In my batch file, I would like to create this folder structure by levels as I mentioned below and delete the folder which refers to Level 4AA.

I'm a newbie so I have nothing in my batch file yet.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Edited. I'm getting confused. Until now you didn't mention creating folders, only excluding... :P hope I'm helping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop to get the parent folder for a given folder:

```
set target_dir=C:\temp\root\students\type1.test\assignment1

for %%a in ("%target_dir%") do (
    echo Removing %%~dpa%
    rd /s/q %%~dpa%
)
```